# installDebug stuck on 99% only for real device (USB) but work fine on emulator

Tags: android, react-native, usb, adb, device

I can run my RN application on installed emulator but when I try to install it on my real device (connected via USB) like I always did it stucks at `installDebug 99%`.

running command adb devices is okey, that shows me that my devices is connected successfully:
[image]

I don't know if I can provide more informations, but working with an old macbook I was only testing with my real device

Comment: Hand you tried uninstalling the app from the device and rebuilding?

Comment: @Robert I try to run npx react-native run-android I don't install APK it's just an install debug

Comment: @Abe yes whene I get this probleme I checked if I had uninstall the app before of course but it still stucks